# Equivalence of Supremum and the Limit

Tags: calculus

My professor gave the following example in class:

Let $ a_1, a_2, $... be a sequence in nonnegative extended real numbers.

Then $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i := \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i:= \sup \limits_{F\subseteq N \\for~\ all~\ finite} \sum\limits_{i \in F} a_i $

I am trying to prove why these two definitions are equivalent to each other. In other words I want to prove that

$$ A=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i \iff A = \sup \limits_{F\subseteq N \\for~\ all~\ finite} \sum\limits_{i \in F} a_i $$

**Possible solution:** I am trying to claim that $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i $ is a a nondeacresing function $ f: N \rightarrow [0,\infty] $ but I have difficulty to justify that for any $ n \in N $, $ f(n) $ is well defined. i.e. f assigns only one nonnegative number to this sum no matter how we sum up terms. Which axiom on real numbers make sure this is  the case.

Any hints or even the full solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $\mathbb{N}$ the set of positive integers, and denote by $\mathcal{F}$ the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Define
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &:= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i, \\
\beta &:= \sup_{F \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{i \in F} a_i.
\end{align}
$$

Since, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}_1$, $a_i \geq 0$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are well-defined, and $\alpha, \beta \in [0,\infty]$ (in particular, it may be that $\alpha = \infty$ or that $\beta = \infty$). Another consequence of the non-negativity of the $a_i$'s is the the partial sums in the definition of $\alpha$ form a non-decreasing sequence.

We wish to show that $\alpha = \beta$.

We firstly show that $\alpha \leq \beta$. It suffices to show that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \leq \beta.
$$
Let then $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $F := \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$. Then $F \in \mathcal{F}$, and
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = \sum_{i \in F} a_i \leq \beta.
$$

Next, we show that $\alpha \geq \beta$. It suffices to show that, for every $F \in \mathcal{F}$,
$$
\sum_{i \in F} a_i \leq \alpha.
$$
Let then $F \in \mathcal{F}$. If $F = \emptyset$, then, by convention
$$
\sum_{i \in F} a_i = 0,
$$
and we're done. Otherwise, define $n^* := \max F$ (since $F$ is finite, the maximum is well-defined). Then
$$
\sum_{i \in F} a_i \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n^*} a_i \leq \alpha.
$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thanks but I am exactly interested in this. You claim the following: "Since, for every $i \in \mathbb{N}_1$, $a_i \geq 0$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are well-defined". How one would justify that? Using induction? I might be too picky on this small details which might be too trivial for mathematician but since I am starting to learn mathematics rigorously that is why I am interested in all the details. Thanks again.

Comment: @G.T.: $\beta$ is well-defined regardless of the non-negativity of the $a_i$'s because a supremum is always well-defined. As for $\alpha$, every monotone sequence has a limit in the extended real numbers. The non-negativity of the $a_i$'s guarantees that the sequence of partial sums $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ is monotone non-decreasing.

Comment: @G.T.: Is there any other difficulty in my answer that I can help you with?

Comment: I am working through it right now. For example, I just proved for myself that if each member of the sequence is less than some number than the limit is also less than that number. (I did not ask that because I am trying to avoid trivial questions) I did that and now I am progressing through the proof. I will ask you for help if anything is not clear for me. I will accept your answer as soon as I fully understand the proof. :)

Comment: In the last step you use the fact that limit of non-decreasing sequence is not less than any member of the sequence right? Then everything is clear. With your permission I will include this trivial details in your proof okay?

Comment: @G.T.: Correct! Thanks for accepting my answer. I feel that you understand the proof very well indeed, so there is no point in adding anything to it now. Good luck with your studies!